# ggplot2 - plotting fitted values for different conditions of a control variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

`preds` is a data frame with info about probabilities predicted from a logistic regression model.

[image]
[Here's a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TFiwRY8pYs7VWBgKWJupSzfzW2mrogCTWgAD8jJiW2A/edit?usp=sharing).

I need to plot two lines and their associated confidence intervals. One line should represent the relationship between `ingr_chocolate` and `predProb` by the value of `type_hard`. I'm most of the way there, but am missing the confidence intervals for one line:

```
ggplot(joe_pred2b, aes(x=type_hard, y=predProbs)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = LL, ymax = UL), alpha = 0.2) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=factor(ingr_chocolate)), size=1)
```

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try using `geom_line` rather than `geom_point` and use `aes(color=factor(ingr_chocolate))` to let ggplot know the value is discrete rather than continuous.

Comment: Thanks - edited the Q to show where I got with your suggestion + another edit

Comment: Put `group = factor(ingr_chocolate)` inside `aes()` in either `ggplot()` or in `geom_ribbon()`. Need this to tell ggplot that there should be 2 ribbons.